# Material Design Textfield Custom Class Not Showing Up in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have installed the MaterialComponents/TextFields pod, and I am trying to add a new text field into the storyboard editor.  I add a textfield, and when I go to add a Material textfield custom class from the dropdown in the identity inspector, none of the material textfields that come with the pod show up. Is there something that I'm missing that needs to be done before I can use these custom classes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead - reinstalling the pod or restart Xcode or import Material components in swift file. Hope it works

Comment: I have reinstalled and restarted about a million times, but now that you say import components in a swift file, I should mention that when I install the pod, and navigate to the files themselves in the xcode navigator, i notice that they are all .m or .h files.  None of them are .swift files.  I diddnt think this was a problem being that I downloaded these files directly from Google on the page meant for swift development, but do you think the fact that they arent .swift files could be the reason?

Comment: @JakimBeaufort Pod files may come in objective c or swift files which is not a big concern. Make sure you are opening the .xcworkspace file, not the .xcodeproj file. In identity inspector provide the class **MDCTextField** for the pod MaterialComponents/TextFields